# socket programming client freezing python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

Basically, I have a python client to send command to ask server do somethings, I have implemented threading, but it seems not working. For example, when I send "start" command to the server, it will execute job_function, but during this time, the client is freezing. So basically, I want my server still able to respond to client's request, while executing tasks, and that's the reason I use thread.

Server.py:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 5005))  # Bind to the port
s.listen(1)  # Now wait for client connection.
c, addr = s.accept()  # Establish connection with client.

while True:
    print('Got connection from', addr)
    data = c.recv(1024).decode()
    print(data)
    if data == "start":
        print("start the service")
        c.sendall('started service'.encode())

        threading.Thread(target=job_function).start()

    elif data == "suspend":
        print("suspend service")
        c.sendall('suspended service'.encode())
    else:
        c.sendall('wrong command'.encode())

c.close()  # Close the connection
```

Client.py:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1',5005))

while True:
   x = input("Enter command: ")
   s.sendall(x.encode())
   print(x)
   data = s.recv(1024).decode()
   print(data)
s.close()
```

Comment: How about `multiprocessing` instead of `threading`? It is more reliable when it comes to concurrent actions

Comment: If you use blocking I/O, then whatever thread calls recv() will remain inside recv() until some data is received (or the socket is closed, whichever comes first).  So if no data is ever received but the TCP connection remains open, then the recv() call may never return, leaving your thread (more or less) permanently frozen.  To get around this problem I use non-blocking I/O instead (with or without threads), so that I don't have to worry about getting stuck in send() or recv().  I have my thread(s) block inside select() while waiting for I/O, to avoid busy-looping the CPU.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Can you give me an example of non-blocking with threads? Much appreciate it.

Comment: @Brandon for non-blocking I/O using select(), see here:  https://pymotw.com/2/select/

As far as combining it with threads is concerned, you can just use a separate select()-loop for each thread.  Each thread will spend most of its time blocked inside select().  If you want a mechanism to make a thread exit cleanly, you can have select() listen on an additional socket, and then when you want the thread to go away, send some data to that socket (and program your event loop to know that receiving any data on that socket means it is time for the thread to exit)

Comment: Make sure you include *all* the code of the server (it's missing some things) and all steps to reproduce.  I made small changes to makes server work and it worked and never paused.  Do realize that TCP is a streams bytes but has no concept of messages, so a protocol should be in place to ensure the messages are sent and received completely.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done only using recv() function.

client side:

```
                    sssize = os.stat('fileName').st_size
                    file = open('fileName', 'rb')
                    amm = file.read(sssize)

                    dfd = amm
                    #########
                    c.send(bytes(str(sssize), 'utf-8'))
                    rrespo = c.recv(1024).decode()

                    ######
                    if rrespo == 'yess':
                        m = 0
                        lenmsg = 1024
                        loop = (int((sssize) / lenmsg))


                        if (sssize)<lenmsg:
                            c.send(dfd[0:sssize])
                        else:
                            dddf='oksend'

                            for ioo in range(0, loop):
                                if dddf=='oksend':
                                    c.send(dfd[ioo * lenmsg:ioo * lenmsg + lenmsg])
                                    stloop = ioo * lenmsg + lenmsg
                                    print(int(m / (loop - 1) * 100))
                                    m = m + 1
                                    dddf = c.recv(6).decode()
                                    print(dddf, ioo)



                            nextloop = sssize - loop * lenmsg
                            if nextloop > 0:
                                c.send(dfd[stloop:stloop + nextloop])




                        file.close()
                        print('file transffered successfully')
```

Server Side:

```
                        filename = input(str("Enter file name :")
                        fill = open(filename, 'wb')
                        c.send(bytes(commm, 'utf-8'))
                        # sizze=c.recv(1024).decode()
                        # print('size')
                        # print(sizze)
                        # c.send(bytes('done', 'utf-8'))
                        fileSize = c.recv(1024).decode()
                        c.send(bytes('yess', 'utf-8'))
                        lenmsg=1024

                        loop = int(int(fileSize) / lenmsg)

                        if (int(fileSize))<lenmsg:
                            image = c.recv(int(fileSize))
                            fill.write(image)
                        else:
                            for i in range(0, loop):
                                image = c.recv(lenmsg)

                                fill.write(image)
                                print('completed downloading:', int((i / (loop - 1) * 100)), '%')
                                c.send(bytes('oksend', 'utf-8'))

                            nextloop = int(fileSize) - loop * lenmsg
                            if nextloop > 0:
                                image = c.recv(nextloop)
                                fill.write(image)
                        fill.close()
                        print('file downloaded successfully')
```